# What should I concern when I want to ask Third party to build my website?

Tags: development

From last year, I sell my products using facebook. I found that my business is finding its maximum profit, because the average profit every month is around one static point. Right now, I'm trying to expand my business by selling my products using our own website. For this idea, I would like to ask a third party to build my own business website. What I want to ask is what should I concern when I want to ask third party to build my business website?

For this question, I would prefer the your answers are related to technical issues, such as security, response latency, and etc..

Answer (score 2):

When talking to a web developer, there are a lot of things you can cover right off the bat. First and foremost, how much is this webdev going to charge? Second, draft up a timeline of the most preferred development time, and checkpoints inbetween now and then when your webdev will check in with you to get feedback from you, plus you can make sure he/she is actually building the site.

You can use several services for using a freelancer, such as [odesk.com](https://www.odesk.com/) or [freelancer.com](http://freelancer.com/). With the freelancing service and your legally binding entity, you can make sure that the webdev doesn't screw you over by just ditching you. Below is a short list of what should come from the developer and you, but it certainly isn't everything you need as that is done in a case-by-case basis.

### From The Developer

- Price
- Development Timeline (Important: Make sure he/she checks in with you on a regular basis)
- Skills
- Past projects
- Planned Webhost

### From you

- Price
- Required Development Timeline
- Special functionality (Login system, shopping cart, etc.)
- Number of pages
- Preferred Webhost

Don't forget to do your research. Look into your freelancer as much as you can, and research all technologies or services he/she recommends. You have the money, you have the control.

Comment: how about the technical issue? kind of its security, response latency and etc. Please share your experiences..

Comment: On the technical side of the house, most of it should be covered post-development as problems arise. The only exception is security. If you're going to use a shopping cart, there are a lot of third-party software available for that as well as services to handle the transactions. Like I said, if you need a shopping cart, heavily research anything he/she suggests to make sure it is good enough for your standards. With latency, you won't know 100% until it's done and there are a lot of dev techniques to help that. Everything else is handled by your web host which you should, of course, research.